# Concurrent connections to the same table

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

We are a small firm, with about 10 people using a database server.

I have this application that connects to a database and fills about 40 rows of data in an table. Then calls a stored procedure to process the data before inserting the data back into another table and then truncates the table.

Is it possible if two people run the application at the same time, the data can be nonsensical. If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Lock the table (for reading). Second session will not access locked data.

Comment: what engine are you using? Oracle / MySQL / MSSQL / PostgreSQL?

Comment: @AMG mysql innodb

Comment: @Akina will the second session continue once the lock is lifted or not continue at all. The entire process finishes fairly quickly, takes 0.2 seconds, and I added additional logic to the code to check if the table is truncated before executing the query

Comment: So... please confirm if this is what your program automatically executes: creates session -> begins transaction ->  inserts 40 records in table A -> processes the data -> saves the data into table B -> truncates the table A -> Commits transaction-> Closes connection. Is this correct?

Comment: The second session can do nothing until first session unlocks the table. And - use R/W lock.

Comment: @AMG thats correct, if by session you are talking about the connection string that looks like this `rs.Open strsql1, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`,`rs.Open strsql2, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`,`rs.Open strsql3, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`. It's a sequence of SQL statement to perform the task, but there is nothing in the code about closing the connection or "committing the transaction", note this is vba in excel.

Comment: Ok, then... please find my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use temporary tables instead of insert and truncate. 
They are invisible to other sessions, so you can have many sessions creating the same "TEMPTABLEA", inserting records, deleting records, and even destroying the TEMP TABLE without interfering other users work. When you kill the session, the Temp Table automatically is destroyed.

I'll put a fragment of VBA code that you must addapt to yours. 
(make sure you have these references
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library and
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.1 Library 
)

This is the code:

```
Public Sub Routine()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Cnxn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strCnxn As String

    Dim sqlStr0 As String
    'Dim ...all SQL strings you need
    'Dim ...all recordsets you need


    'Open Connection and begin transaction
    strCnxn = "Provider='sqloledb';Data Source='MySqlServer';" & _
                "Initial Catalog='[Your Data base here]';Integrated Security='SSPI';"
    Set Cnxn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cnxn.Open strCnxn
    Cnxn.BeginTrans

    'Sql String to create a TEMPORARY TABLE using YOUR ORIGIN TABLE as a TEMPLATE
    sqlStr0 = "create temporary table TempTableA as select * from tableA where 1 = 2;"
    Cnxn.Execute sqlStr0

    'Put your code here to insert the 40 records into TempTableA
    'Put your code here to move records from TempTableA to definitive TableB
    'Do not worry about TempTableA anymore. It will be destroyed.

    Cnxn.CommitTrans
    Cnxn.Close
    Set Cnxn = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' clean up
    If Not Cnxn Is Nothing Then
        If Cnxn.State = adStateOpen Then
            Cnxn.RollbackTrans
            Cnxn.Close
        End If
        Set Cnxn = Nothing
    End If
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

- At the beginning of the operations use `SELECT GET_LOCK('no-nonsense');`
- At the end, do `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('no-nonsense');`